# Unable to use decimal points on spinner button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell (B3( which i initially used spinner button so that the values will iterate and the tables that uses that cell for a specified formula will auto update. However I realised that the spinner only accepts integers . My cell contains decimal points 4.5% and 5% respectively. i did a checkbox but i realise I need different cells to create the checkbox and validate accordingly. My ideal result would be something like the spinner button whereby the cell auto reiterates from 4.5% to 5% respectively this is so that all other cells that reference to b3 would auto update ,each time its value changes to 4.5 or 5 . Some help would be very much appreciated! Is it possible to do the non-vba way or do I have to do some coding to achieve my goal?

Comment: Add a formula next to cell B3:  `=$B$3/2` and reference other cells to that. The formula will increment by 0.5.  If you only want 4.5 and 5 just set your minimum to 9 and your maximum to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with @jkpieterse and his / her solution. Yet, it requires a helper column (very much like the comment provided above). Hence, I felt compelled to add another solution which works without a helper column.

While this solution works without a helper column it does not provide the values you are looking for but merely "visually" mimics these values. Here is what it **looks** like:

[image]

You can see that it **look** as if it does what you want it to do. But instead, the values in the cell are 500 and more. The tweak here is to use the number format of the cell with a trailing `.` which (that's the thousand-separator in my localization) ensures that the value `1,000` is shown as `0.5` and the `%` is merely added as a text to the end of the value. So, in US localization I'd assume that the number format should be something like this: `0.0,"%"`.

Then you'll get values of 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, etc in the cell. But they will be shown as 0.5%, 1.0%, 1.5%, 2.0%, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a helper cell as the linkedcell of the spinner and add/subtract the value of the helpercell divided by for example 1000. So if C1 is the linked cell, put a formula like this in the cell you want the spinner to change:

=4%+$C$1/1000